# programmatically check items in a QAbstractItemModel / QTreeView

Tags: qt, model, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I am trying to use a selection (QModelIndexList) to check all the selected items of a QTreeView.

I use `setData` with the `Qt::CheckStateRole` on the indexes and the data seems updated.
I am emitting `dataChanged` signal but the tree is not redrawn (with and without the role given as argument).
Is this an issue of the selection model?

It works if I do `beginResetModel` but my tree gets collapsed which a deal breaker.

How can I manage to get my item repainted?

Here is the method I added in my model

```
void MyModel::checkSelectedItems( const QModelIndexList &checkedIndexes, bool check )
{
    QVector<int> roles = QVector<int>() << Qt::CheckStateRole;
  for ( const QModelIndex &index : checkedIndexes)
  {
      setData(index, check ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);
      emit dataChanged(index, index); //), roles);
  }
}
```

and the call to it:

```
myModel->checkSelectedItems( myTree->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes(), true );
```

After the call, the selection is grey (and not blue anymore) but still "selected". Clicking anywhere refresh the tree and correctly shows the checked items.

Comment: After `myModel->checkSelectedItems( myTree->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes(), true );` write `myTree->update();`.

Comment: that does not seem to solve the issue, also tried to call `myTree->update(index)` with the modified index.

Comment: I am sorry! In this moment I don't have further ideas. I will check that again later.

Comment: no worries, it was worth a try, thanks for the hint!

Comment: also tried `myTree->viewPort()->update()` without more sucess

Comment: `myTree->repaint()` solved the issue, but I am not sure this is the correct approach.

Comment: Well, the documentation of [repaint](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#repaint) states, that _In almost all circumstances update() is better, as it permits Qt to optimize for speed and minimize flicker._ But when `update` doesn't work, then `repaint` should be used, as you already did.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show works mostly fine in spite of being incorrect. Please amend the question to include a reproduction case. But yes, the code does have problems.

It is in `setData`'s contract to emit the `dataChanged` signal; any code where `dataChanged` is emitted outside of `setData` indicates a broken implementation of the model. You should move the signal emission to `MyModel::setData`. The only other place where it'd be valid to emit `dataChanged` is in a slot/functor in a proxy model, but only when the slot/functor is connected to the `sourceModel`'s `dataChanged` signal.

> myTree->repaint() solved the issue

Invoking `repaint()` or `update()` outside of a widget's implementation is almost always an error, and indicates that the widget is either not used properly or is not implemented properly. In your case, it's the former: the model's `setData` is broken and doesn't emit `dataChanged`.

<sub><sup>For inspiration on how such a test case might look like, see e.g. [this answer](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/filesystem-model-select-50132273). In a nutshell: aim for 100 lines or less, single file, `#include <QtWidgets>` at the beginning, no unnecessary code nor boilerplate. Make it sweet and simple :)</sup></sub>